# Problems restarting Neo4j 1.8.1

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j version 1.8.1.

When I stopped the Neo4j service and started it up again, it will not respond at all.
I am unable to connect to the database using the Neo4j browser even though the service is running.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue? It was working fine until I restarted the service.

Thanks

Comment: If the shutdown was unclean, it may take some time for recovery on next startup. Wait a while. The time taken is directly proportional to amount of data in the db. If thats not the case please check logs.

Comment: Can you try connecting via the shell? bin\Neo4jShell -path <path to db>  If this was an unclean shutdown then you would see the recovery messages and your shell will start up once fully recovered. Once done, exit cleanly and try starting the service. As mentioned by Gopi, if that doesn't happen you'll have to check the logs

Comment: Hi Gopi, can you put that comment as a response.....that way, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you log Java's garbage collection to a file, you can tail this file to get a clue how busy `neo4j` is during startup, especially, as pointed out, following an unclean shutdown.

The Java startup option you need is:

```
-Xloggc:neo4j-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```